# Is it possible to index nested attributes with ArangoSearch Views?

Tags: arangodb

I would like to create an ArangoSearch view on the following document:

```
  "Title": [
    {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "Game of thrones"
    },
    {
      "lang": "fr",
      "value": "Throne de fer"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried to link the view like this :

```
{"links": {
    "SearchTest": {
      "analyzers": [
        "identity",
        "text_en",
        "text_fr"
      ],
      "fields": {
        "Title[0].value": {
          "analyzers": [
            "text_en"
          ]
        },
        "Title[1].value": {
          "analyzers": [
            "text_fr"
          ]
        }
      },
      "includeAllFields": true,
      "storeValues": "id",
      "trackListPositions": false
    }
  }}
```

But I doesn't seem to work

Here's the query

```
FOR d IN SearchTestVW SEARCH PHRASE(d.Title[0].value,'Game','text_en') RETURN d
```

It doesn't return any results. Is it even possible to do this? I have tried with root attributes and it works fine. But our documents are structured like this.

Answer (score 1):

Nesting is possible using `fields: { "objectName": fields: "fieldName"}`. If you define all analyzers on the "root" level and set `includeAllFields` to `true`, you don't even need to specify the fields individually.

You have the possibility to use the analyzer at the object level and just define which attributes should be covered by the search index. That reduces the size of the index and you could exclude fields that may just add 'noise' to the results.

```
  "links": {
    "SearchTest": {
      "analyzers": [
        "identity"
      ],
      "fields": {
        "Title": {
          "analyzers": [
            "text_en"
          ],
          "fields": {
            "value": {},
            "lang": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "includeAllFields": false,
      "storeValues": "none",
      "trackListPositions": false
```

Now this should work:

`FOR d IN SearchTestVW SEARCH PHRASE(d.Title.value,'Game','text_en') RETURN d`